# copying only filtered data without advanced filter and keeping the original filter on the original table

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, copy

I have a code that copies data from different workbooks to an array and transfers that data to a table I want to keep the filter method with a slicer on the workbook I copy that data from but to copy only the filtered data.
on the workbook I am copying to I want only the filtered that to be seen
Does anyone have suggestions?

- I commented out the offset because the code doesn't work i need the offset in order not to copy the header row

```
    Sub readingarray()
    
    
    Dim table_list_object As ListObject
    Dim table_object_row As ListRow
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim tbl As Range
    
    Set tbl = Workbooks("test.xlsm").Worksheets("shibuz").Range("T4").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'arr = tbl.Offset(1, 0).Resize(tbl.Rows.Count - 1, tbl.Columns.Count)
    arr = tbl
    
    Set table_list_object = Workbooks("shibuzim 2 updated.xlsm").Worksheets("shibuz").ListObjects("LeaveTracker")
    Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add
    
    Dim rowcount As Long, columncount As Long
     rowcount = UBound(arr, 1)
     columncount = UBound(arr, 2)
    table_object_row.Range(1, 1).Resize(rowcount, columncount).Value = arr
    End Sub
```

Comment: the way i have it set now it copies only the header line from the table

Answer (score 0):

solved it, hopes this might help

```
Option Explicit


Sub readingarray()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim table_list_object As ListObject
Dim table_object_row As ListRow
Dim arr
Dim Itm
Dim rng As Range
Dim stringarray As Variant
Dim rowcount As Long, columncount As Long
stringarray = Array("test.xlsm", "test 2.xlsm")
 On Error Resume Next
    For Each Itm In stringarray
       
    
        arr = GetArrayFromFilteredRange(Workbooks(Itm).Worksheets("shibuz").ListObjects("LeaveTracker").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
         Set table_list_object = Workbooks("shibuzim 2 updated.xlsm").Worksheets("shibuz").ListObjects("LeaveTracker")
         Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add

    
        rowcount = UBound(arr, 1)
        columncount = UBound(arr, 2)
        table_object_row.Range(1, 1).Resize(rowcount - 1, columncount - 1).Value = arr
    Next Itm
    
  On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Function GetArrayFromFilteredRange(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim arr As Variant
    
   helper.Cells.Clear
    rng.Copy helper.Range("A1")
    arr = helper.UsedRange.Value
    
    GetArrayFromFilteredRange = arr
End Function
```